# LCD 2*16 custom characters

Tags: lcd, character-lcd

I need to write custom characters in LCD 2*16.

I use CGRAM to make custom characters but as far as I know, I can't write more than 8 custom characters at a time (please tell me if I'm wrong).

I'm using the LPC1788 to interface to the Alphanumeric LCD.

What can I do to show more than 8 custom characters at a time on LCD 2*16?

Comment: I believe this is a limitation of the Hitachi design (a design that almost everyone who makes alpha numeric LEDs uses).  Armed with that knowledge you can dive into this more.  But, if true, the only alternative I know of is to use such a large display that there are 2 copies of the Hitachi design thereby giving you a set of custom characters for the top 2 rows and another set of custom characters for the bottom 2 rows.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a LCD which is a combination of an alpha numeric display and a graphical display.   It will only be black and white and the resolution is no better than an alpha numeric LCD.   But the dots are evenly spaced and can also be used to display low resolution graphics.  Say if this is what you are searching for and I'll make a more formal answer of it.

Comment: @st2000 no I made my choice and used qapass 16×2 I can't change my lcd

Comment: Just keep changing the CGRAM between writing characters. Changing the CGRAM doesn't change what is on-screen.

Comment: @tom carpenter unfortunately it does change!

Comment: Interesting. Didn't think it did. Clearly I remembered wrong.

Comment: In which case the answer is you can't show more than 8.

Comment: Well then, it is what it is.  But there are other alternatives in addition to the ones I spoke of.  Even color ones which completely diverge from the Hitachi paradigm.  And these color screens are surprisingly cheap and easy to control.  Even for the simplest embedded processors. Again,  say if this is what you are searching for and I'll make a more formal answer of it.

Comment: @st2000 Would you please name some other Alphanumeric lcd without hitachi controller?

Comment: I am not sure you understand.  The Hitachi controller design is ubiquitous.  And has, because of this, been adapted everywhere.  Even in the software driver I assume you are using (or did you write your own driver from scratch?).  If you didn't use this type of interface - you would literally be starting over.  It would be easier to switch to a hybrid Hitachi / Graphical LCD as I suggested earlier.  That said - maybe you will be lucky and find a variation with more custom characters.  If you feel luckly - keep searching.

Comment: There is a description about character verses graphical LCDs [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/character-lcds/character-vs-graphical-lcds).  But w/o knowing what you are doing it is difficult to suggest this alternative.  Also, consider [this](https://www.adafruit.com/product/358) color display.  Likely is does not resemble a Hitachi interface at all.  It can be controlled by as small a processor as an Arduino Uno.  So likely can be controlled by what ever you are using.  But, again, w/o knowing what your goals are it is very difficult to suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 6):

If the datasheet says you only get 8 custom characters, then you only get 8 custom characters.  If there are more than 8 characters that you need but aren't part of the standard set provided by that LCD, then that LCD is not for you.